# How to handle different dependencies requirements for web servers in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, primefaces, glassfish

I'm trying to write an application that can be run on WildFly 8, Tomcat 7 and GlassFish 4 using JSF and PrimeFaces.  Here is my situation

For **WildFly** I include nothing

For **GlassFish** I need to include:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

For **TomCat** I need to include

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency> 
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm relatively new to Maven but I'd like to be able to put together a project that is "easy" for people to run.  Would I make different "directives" that would build a web-container specific version?  Do I need 3 separate pom files?  Can maven have conditional includes? Do I have pom-tomcat.xml pom-glassfish.xml pom-wildfly.xml and somehow you point at one of those files and it includes other things?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Tomcat is a servlet Engine whereas Glassfish and Wildfly are Application servers. So there must be differences. For example javax.inject who is the implemtation on Tomcat? Have you done the injection yourself by Guice/Spring?

Comment: Everything "works" but i just had to read up on the different dependencies for the different combos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to implement it with Maven is using [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), e.g.:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tomcat</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency><!--tomcat dependencies--></dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>glassfish</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency><!--glassfish dependencies--></dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

and then you can build it for glassfish or tomcat:

```
    mvn -P glassfish
    mvn -P tomcat
```

(Side question is why not just include all the same dependencies in all cases?)

Comment: Unfortunatly some of the WebServers already have their own version of some of these classes and it causes crashes if they are included.  I did some googling and found bug reports which say to include/exclude various libraries for each situation.

Comment: You can't produce the artifacts with a single build. You need to call Maven for every environment separately. Bust best is to call Maven just once and getting all artifacts for all environments.

Comment: While as you have it here it is technically possible to have different dependencies in different profiles, this is a terrible idea. These profiles will NEVER be activated when the war is retrieved from a repository manager and therefore any downstream artifacts from the WAR (e.g. an ear containing the war) will be wrong..  Maven practice would be to have two different modules for the different deployment platforms.

Comment: Using modules is also a workaround, and I think splitting project to modules based on dependencies and runtime packaging needs alone, not on code/hierarchical organization of the code, is (in your words) "a terrible idea" as well. It's not intuitive, module support even with latest maven is still at times crippled, potentially complicates build and so on. 
Profiles on the other hand are simple and clearly declare the intent. It can also manage the final name of the package. Although RM was never a part of the question, so I am not sure if the original author even cares about that...